# Error on MapView (IOS) and llvm

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, llvm

Created a new project, and place on controller view MapView, then compile, and got error:

```
LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: 0xac06488: v16i8 = X86ISD::PSHUFB 0xac04da0, 0xa3c5570 [ID=502]
  0xac04da0: v16i8 = llvm.x86.sse2.packuswb.128 0xac04d18, 0xac04c08, 0xac04c90 [ORD=1614] [ID=501]
    0xac04d18: i32 = TargetConstant<2543> [ORD=1614] [ID=33]
    0xac04c08: v8i16 = llvm.x86.sse2.packssdw.128 0xabf5f70, 0xabf5a20, 0xabf5bb8 [ORD=1612] [ID=500]
      0xabf5f70: i32 = TargetConstant<2541> [ORD=1612] [ID=32]
      0xabf5a20: v4i32 = llvm.x86.sse2.cvttps2dq 0xabf5998, 0xabf5910 [ORD=1602] [ID=498]
        0xabf5998: i32 = TargetConstant<2528> [ORD=1602] [ID=31]
        0xabf5910: v4f32 = fadd 0xabf5778, 0xac04fc0 [ORD=1601] [ID=495]
          0xabf5778: v4f32 = fmul 0xabf5118, 0xabf5888 [ORD=1600] [ID=492]
            0xabf5118: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.min.ps 0xa3d39a0, 0xabf5090, 0xa3c1cf0 [ORD=1587] [ID=489]
              0xa3d39a0: i32 = TargetConstant<2700> [ORD=1406] [ID=23]
              0xabf5090: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.max.ps 0xa3bdd70, 0xabf5008, 0xa3bed70 [ORD=1586] [ID=486]
                0xa3bdd70: i32 = TargetConstant<2698> [ORD=1456] [ID=27]
                0xabf5008: v4f32,ch = load 0xabfa170, 0xabd68b0, 0xa3bb570<LD16[%429](tbaa=!"omnipotent char")> [ORD=1585] [ID=482]
                  0xabd68b0: i32 = FrameIndex<1> [ORD=1190] [ID=4]
                  0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
                0xa3bed70: v4f32 = bitcast 0xa3c81b8 [ID=124]
                  0xa3c81b8: v4i32 = BUILD_VECTOR 0xa3c8130, 0xa3c8130, 0xa3c8130, 0xa3c8130 [ID=98]




              0xa3c1cf0: v4f32,ch = load 0x9a78fac, 0xa3c6be0, 0xa3bb570<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=146]
                0xa3c6be0: i32 = add 0xa3c17a0, 0xa3c22c8 [ID=127]
                  0xa3c17a0: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=55]
                  0xa3c22c8: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xa3c6718 [ID=99]

                0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
            0xabf5888: v4f32,ch = load 0x9a78fac, 0xac05eb0, 0xa3bb570<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=156]
              0xac05eb0: i32 = add 0xa3c17a0, 0xac15ae8 [ID=137]
                0xa3c17a0: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=55]
                0xac15ae8: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabf5668 [ID=109]
                  0xabf5668: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=65]
              0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
          0xac04fc0: v4f32,ch = load 0x9a78fac, 0xac15d18, 0xa3bb570<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=157]
            0xac15d18: i32 = add 0xa3c17a0, 0xac05fc0 [ID=138]
              0xa3c17a0: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=55]
              0xac05fc0: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabf5800 [ID=110]
                0xabf5800: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=66]
            0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
      0xabf5bb8: v4i32 = llvm.x86.sse2.cvttps2dq 0xabf5998, 0xabf5b30 [ORD=1605] [ID=497]
        0xabf5998: i32 = TargetConstant<2528> [ORD=1602] [ID=31]
        0xabf5b30: v4f32 = fadd 0xabf5aa8, 0xac04fc0 [ORD=1604] [ID=494]
          0xabf5aa8: v4f32 = fmul 0xabf52b0, 0xabf5888 [ORD=1603] [ID=491]
            0xabf52b0: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.min.ps 0xa3d39a0, 0xabf5228, 0xa3c1cf0 [ORD=1591] [ID=488]
              0xa3d39a0: i32 = TargetConstant<2700> [ORD=1406] [ID=23]
              0xabf5228: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.max.ps 0xa3bdd70, 0xabf51a0, 0xa3bed70 [ORD=1590] [ID=484]
                0xa3bdd70: i32 = TargetConstant<2698> [ORD=1456] [ID=27]
                0xabf51a0: v4f32,ch = load 0xabfa170, 0xabd7240, 0xa3bb570<LD16[%433](tbaa=!"omnipotent char")> [ORD=1589] [ID=481]
                  0xabd7240: i32 = add 0xabd68b0, 0xabd7350 [ORD=1418] [ID=74]


                  0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
                0xa3bed70: v4f32 = bitcast 0xa3c81b8 [ID=124]
                  0xa3c81b8: v4i32 = BUILD_VECTOR 0xa3c8130, 0xa3c8130, 0xa3c8130, 0xa3c8130 [ID=98]




              0xa3c1cf0: v4f32,ch = load 0x9a78fac, 0xa3c6be0, 0xa3bb570<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=146]
                0xa3c6be0: i32 = add 0xa3c17a0, 0xa3c22c8 [ID=127]
                  0xa3c17a0: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=55]
                  0xa3c22c8: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xa3c6718 [ID=99]

                0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
            0xabf5888: v4f32,ch = load 0x9a78fac, 0xac05eb0, 0xa3bb570<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=156]
              0xac05eb0: i32 = add 0xa3c17a0, 0xac15ae8 [ID=137]
                0xa3c17a0: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=55]
                0xac15ae8: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabf5668 [ID=109]
                  0xabf5668: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=65]
              0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
          0xac04fc0: v4f32,ch = load 0x9a78fac, 0xac15d18, 0xa3bb570<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=157]
            0xac15d18: i32 = add 0xa3c17a0, 0xac05fc0 [ID=138]
              0xa3c17a0: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=55]
              0xac05fc0: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabf5800 [ID=110]
                0xabf5800: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=66]
            0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
    0xac04c90: v8i16 = llvm.x86.sse2.packssdw.128 0xabf5f70, 0xabf5d50, 0xabf5ee8 [ORD=1613] [ID=499]
      0xabf5f70: i32 = TargetConstant<2541> [ORD=1612] [ID=32]
      0xabf5d50: v4i32 = llvm.x86.sse2.cvttps2dq 0xabf5998, 0xabf5cc8 [ORD=1608] [ID=496]
        0xabf5998: i32 = TargetConstant<2528> [ORD=1602] [ID=31]
        0xabf5cc8: v4f32 = fadd 0xabf5c40, 0xac04fc0 [ORD=1607] [ID=493]
          0xabf5c40: v4f32 = fmul 0xabf5448, 0xabf5888 [ORD=1606] [ID=490]
            0xabf5448: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.min.ps 0xa3d39a0, 0xabf53c0, 0xa3c1cf0 [ORD=1595] [ID=487]
              0xa3d39a0: i32 = TargetConstant<2700> [ORD=1406] [ID=23]
              0xabf53c0: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.max.ps 0xa3bdd70, 0xabf5338, 0xa3bed70 [ORD=1594] [ID=483]
                0xa3bdd70: i32 = TargetConstant<2698> [ORD=1456] [ID=27]
                0xabf5338: v4f32,ch = load 0xabfa170, 0xabd32d0, 0xa3bb570<LD16[%437](tbaa=!"omnipotent char")> [ORD=1593] [ID=480]
                  0xabd32d0: i32 = add 0xabd68b0, 0xa3c7828 [ORD=1422] [ID=76]


                  0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
                0xa3bed70: v4f32 = bitcast 0xa3c81b8 [ID=124]
                  0xa3c81b8: v4i32 = BUILD_VECTOR 0xa3c8130, 0xa3c8130, 0xa3c8130, 0xa3c8130 [ID=98]




              0xa3c1cf0: v4f32,ch = load 0x9a78fac, 0xa3c6be0, 0xa3bb570<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=146]
                0xa3c6be0: i32 = add 0xa3c17a0, 0xa3c22c8 [ID=127]
                  0xa3c17a0: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=55]
                  0xa3c22c8: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xa3c6718 [ID=99]

                0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
            0xabf5888: v4f32,ch = load 0x9a78fac, 0xac05eb0, 0xa3bb570<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=156]
              0xac05eb0: i32 = add 0xa3c17a0, 0xac15ae8 [ID=137]
                0xa3c17a0: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=55]
                0xac15ae8: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabf5668 [ID=109]
                  0xabf5668: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=65]
              0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
          0xac04fc0: v4f32,ch = load 0x9a78fac, 0xac15d18, 0xa3bb570<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=157]
            0xac15d18: i32 = add 0xa3c17a0, 0xac05fc0 [ID=138]
              0xa3c17a0: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=55]
              0xac05fc0: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabf5800 [ID=110]
                0xabf5800: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=66]
            0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
      0xabf5ee8: v4i32 = llvm.x86.sse2.cvttps2dq 0xabf5998, 0xabf5e60 [ORD=1611] [ID=479]
        0xabf5998: i32 = TargetConstant<2528> [ORD=1602] [ID=31]
        0xabf5e60: v4f32 = fadd 0xabf5dd8, 0xac04fc0 [ORD=1610] [ID=477]
          0xabf5dd8: v4f32 = fmul 0xabf55e0, 0xabf5888 [ORD=1609] [ID=475]
            0xabf55e0: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.min.ps 0xa3d39a0, 0xabf5558, 0xa3c1cf0 [ORD=1599] [ID=473]
              0xa3d39a0: i32 = TargetConstant<2700> [ORD=1406] [ID=23]
              0xabf5558: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.max.ps 0xa3bdd70, 0xabf9ec8, 0xa3bed70 [ORD=1598] [ID=471]
                0xa3bdd70: i32 = TargetConstant<2698> [ORD=1456] [ID=27]
                0xabf9ec8: v4f32 = fadd 0xabf9e40, 0xabf9db8 [ORD=1575] [ID=467]
                  0xabf9e40: v4f32 = fmul 0xa3c8570, 0xac14f38 [ORD=1574] [ID=463]


                  0xabf9db8: v4f32 = fmul 0xac14da0, 0xa3be1c0 [ORD=1573] [ID=418]


                0xa3bed70: v4f32 = bitcast 0xa3c81b8 [ID=124]
                  0xa3c81b8: v4i32 = BUILD_VECTOR 0xa3c8130, 0xa3c8130, 0xa3c8130, 0xa3c8130 [ID=98]




              0xa3c1cf0: v4f32,ch = load 0x9a78fac, 0xa3c6be0, 0xa3bb570<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=146]
                0xa3c6be0: i32 = add 0xa3c17a0, 0xa3c22c8 [ID=127]
                  0xa3c17a0: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=55]
                  0xa3c22c8: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xa3c6718 [ID=99]

                0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
            0xabf5888: v4f32,ch = load 0x9a78fac, 0xac05eb0, 0xa3bb570<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=156]
              0xac05eb0: i32 = add 0xa3c17a0, 0xac15ae8 [ID=137]
                0xa3c17a0: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=55]
                0xac15ae8: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabf5668 [ID=109]
                  0xabf5668: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=65]
              0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
          0xac04fc0: v4f32,ch = load 0x9a78fac, 0xac15d18, 0xa3bb570<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=157]
            0xac15d18: i32 = add 0xa3c17a0, 0xac05fc0 [ID=138]
              0xa3c17a0: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=55]
              0xac05fc0: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabf5800 [ID=110]
                0xabf5800: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=66]
            0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
  0xa3c5570: v16i8 = bitcast 0xac04f38 [ID=162]
    0xac04f38: v2i64,ch = load 0x9a78fac, 0xa3c6a48, 0xa3bb570<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=158]
      0xa3c6a48: i32 = add 0xa3c17a0, 0xabd34f0 [ID=139]
        0xa3c17a0: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=55]
        0xabd34f0: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xa3d3a28 [ID=111]
          0xa3d3a28: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<16 x i8> <i8 2, i8 1, i8 0, i8 3, i8 6, i8 5, i8 4, i8 7, i8 10, i8 9, i8 8, i8 11, i8 14, i8 13, i8 12, i8 15>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=67]
      0xa3bb570: i32 = undef [ORD=1189] [ID=3]
```

In function: gldLLVMFPTransform8

Anyone can help? TNX!

Comment: Please add some code, where you got errors.

Comment: this problem: new project > storyboard > drag on controller MapView > add framework > build > and in simulator got same error